# Caching for model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, models

**product.rb**

```
  has_many :votes
```

**vote.rb**

```
belongs_to :product
```

Every time, i use sorting in my index controller:

**index_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @products = Product.all.sort { |m| m.votes.count }
end
```

So, i think it would be good to cache votes count for each product (create additional column `votesCount` in `products` table)?

If yes, can i preform that using `before_save` and `before_delete` callbacks in **vote.rb** model?

Or what is the best practice method?

Give me some examples please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [**counter_cache**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)

The `:counter_cache` option can be used to make finding the number of belonging objects more efficient

Consider these models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, counter_cache: true
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

With this declaration, Rails will keep the cache value up to date, and then return that value in response to the size method.

Although the `:counter_cache` option is specified on the model that includes the `belongs_to` declaration, the actual column must be added to the associated model. In the case above, you would need to add a column named `orders_count` to the `Customer` model